# UWP ValueConverter from byte[] to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, uwp, ivalueconverter

I have this `ValueConverter` to convert a `byte[]` into a `BitmapImage`:

```
  public class ByteArrayToImageConverter : IValueConverter
  {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            var buffer = (byte[])value;
            var str = new MemoryStream(buffer).AsRandomAccessStream();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(str);
            return bitmapImage;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
  }
```

Strangely enough, when I run the code, the application hangs (**deadlocks**) in the in the line with `SetSource`.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I try use the code below that can convert.

```
var bytes = (byte[])value;

var image = bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();

// decode image
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(image);
image.Seek(0);

// create bitmap
var output = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelHeight, (int)decoder.PixelWidth);
await output.SetSourceAsync(image);
return output;
```

Comment: How would you call this in the Convert method, which you can't declare async? Besides that, creating a WriteableBitmap instead of a BitmapImage doesn't seem to make any sense. Or do you have an explanation?

Comment: @Clemens I just want to tall you another answer for you duplicate question.

Comment: Why "my duplicate question"? I neither asked nor closed the question. Makes no sense, sorry. Besides that the answer is useless in the context of the question.

Comment: @Clemens For this duplicate question. I found the other question have no one who have this way.

Comment: Then you should certainly answer the other question, not this one. But also the other question is clearly about SetSource. Calling SetSourceAsync is not option, here or there.

Comment: @Clemens Dont you know some way to change the asynchronization to synchronization?